# Python - Subtract a number of samples from a given in a dictionary structure

Tags: python, dictionary, extract, label

I have a dict structure with length 5. The dict structure is called "mat_contents". The information is located in "traindata" and their respective labels in "trainlabels". I want to extract a given number of samples from a given label value. For instance, 60 samples (out of 80) from "traindata" with label "trainlabels" equal 1. I have seen some examples in here but they are different from my request.

Assuming this as an example of Input

```
 traindata   trainlabels
a               1 
b               2
c               2
d               1
e               1
f               2
```

The result if I want to extract two random samples of traindata with trainlabels value of 2 could be:

```
   b  
   f
```

Comment: So what you have to do is take train data and then subtract it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I want to substract a given "traindata" information based on a value of "trainlabel"

Answer (score 1):

```
labels = [k for k, v in mat_contents.items() if v == 1]
result = np.random.choice(labels, 2, replace=False)
```

The first line extracts the relevant labels from your dictionary, and the second line chooses a random subset of 2 elements from these labels (without replacement), if numpy is imported as np.

Comment: Thanks  @bigsim. However, using the following command:                               `labels = [mat_contents['traindata'] for mat_contents['traindata'], mat_contents['trainlabels'] in mat_contents.items() if mat_contents['trainlabels'] == '1']
result = np.random.choice(labels, 2, replace=False)`   The object "labels" returns empty. What I'm doing wrong. If it helps, the dataset mat_coments contains data from a .mat file from Matlab using `mat_contents = scipy.io.loadmat('File.mat') `

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood your original post. Reading more closely it looks like your dict looks like this: `{'traindata': [1, 2, ...], 'trainlabels': ['a', 'b', ...]} `(tell me if it doesn't) - then replace the first line with `labels =
 [mat_contents['trainlabels'][i] for i, val in enumerate(mat_contents['traindata']) if val == 1]`, with the 1 in the `val == 1` part replaced by whatever value you want.

Comment: traindata looks: `mat_contents['traindata']
array([[  3.37988024e-01,   2.87425150e-01,   3.36669403e-01, ...,          
          7.93650794e+00,   7.49814148e+01,   3.39940867e+02], ...`
       and trainlabels as  `array([[array(['2'], 
      dtype='<U1')],
       [array(['3'],        
      dtype='<U1')],
       ..., 
       [array(['2'], 
      dtype='<U1')],       
      , dtype=object)`   using your command, I got this error  `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() ` thanks

Comment: What does `mat_contents` look like?

Comment: Like this `{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Wed Jul 05 14:02:28 2017',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'traindata': array([[  3.37988024e-01,   2.87425150e-01,   3.36669403e-01, ...,    3.47222222e+00,   2.89078631e+01,   2.66129299e+02],        
        
        
 'trainlabels': array([[array(['2'], 
       dtype='<U1')],
        [array(['3'], 
       dtype='<U1')],
        [array(['2'], 
       dtype='<U1')],
        ...,               
        [array(['2'], 
       dtype='<U1')]], dtype=object)} `

Comment: Try this instead of what I had above: `[mat_contents['trainlabels'][0][i] for i, val in enumerate(mat_contents['traindata'][0]) if val == 1]`

Comment: I got this error: `IndexError: index 319 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 `

Comment: `[mat_contents['trainlabels'][0][i] for i, val in enumerate(mat_contents['traindata'].flatten()[0]) if val == 1]` ??

Comment: I got this: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable (if you want we can continue in chat)

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo - let's try one more thing... `[mat_contents['trainlabels'][0][i] for i, val in enumerate(mat_contents['traindata'].flatten()) if val == 1]` ??

Comment: Sorry @bigsim but same error `IndexError: index 319 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1` my apologies for the inconveniences

Answer (score -1):

Can you not use a pandas data frame to do this? Link:[Pandas Dataframe Sampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html). This is an example that i have used in the past:

```
    import pandas as pd

    keeping = 0.8
    source = "/path/to/some/file"

    df = pd.DataFrame(source)

    ones = df[df.trainlabels == 1].sample(frac=keeping)
    twos = df[df.trainlabels == 2].sample(frac=keeping)
```