# Python - Filter dictionary with multiple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, subset

My dictionary "mat_contents" looks like this:

```
{'__globals__': [],
'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Wed Jul 05 14:02:28 2017',
'__version__': '1.0',
'traindata': array([[  3.37988024e-01,   2.87425150e-01,   3.36669403e-01, ...,
       3.47222222e+00,   2.89078631e+01,   2.66129299e+02],
    [  3.78449348e-01,   3.68259383e-01,   3.77523300e-01, ...,
       7.93650794e+00,   7.49814148e+01,   3.39940867e+02],
    [  4.20835393e-01,   3.83079983e-01,   4.20191384e-01, ...,
       4.13223140e+00,   3.17110530e+01,   3.13224462e+02],
    ..., 
    [  8.27125382e-01,   8.31804281e-01,   8.29763490e-01, ...,
       2.05761317e+00,   1.37089318e+01,   2.36950648e+02],
    [  6.25915416e-01,   7.65430139e-01,   6.26844490e-01, ...,
       4.38596491e+00,   2.86553873e+01,   4.07901114e+02],
    [  4.66673740e-01,   4.73032714e-01,   4.66367545e-01, ...,
       9.61538462e+00,   2.73538135e+01,   2.90957268e+02]]),
'trainlabels': array([[array(['2'], 
   dtype='<U1')],
    [array(['3'], 
   dtype='<U1')],
    [array(['2'], 
   dtype='<U1')],
    ..., 
    [array(['2'], 
   dtype='<U1')],
    [array(['2'], 
   dtype='<U1')],
    [array(['2'], 
   dtype='<U1')]], dtype=object)}
```

I want to filter (subset) a given number of rows (containing 'traindata' and 'trainlabels') according to a value of trainlabels. So far (with help) I got the following command:

```
labels = [mat_contents['trainlabels'][0][i] for i, val in enumerate(mat_contents['traindata'].flatten()[0]) if val == 1]
 result = np.random.choice(labels, 2, replace=False)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

I tried to solve in a previous question:
[Python - Subtract a number of samples from a given in a dictionary structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219770/python-subtract-a-number-of-samples-from-a-given-in-a-dictionary-structure/45220364?noredirect=1#comment77517149_45220364)

I'm stuck and I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: When you do `mat_contents['traindata'].flatten()[0]` you are first turning your matrix into an array and then slicing, which return a float, which is not iterable as your error says. Try `mat_contents['traindata'].flatten()`, it should run

Comment: Thanks @gionni. I tried and I get this error: `IndexError: index 319 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`